# How to login to the android market using C#?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-play, webrequest

I would like to login to the webpage [Android Market](https://market.android.com/publish/Home) using C#. I spent the whole day reading about HTTP requests and POST data, but nothing seems to work. What I can do is read the webpage that holds the google login form. But reading the page AFTER the login seems impossible...

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this?

BTW: The code I've tried is shown below:

```
string mail = "XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com";
string pw = "XXXXXXXXXX";

// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (@"https://market.android.com/publish");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = String.Format ("Email={0}&Passwd={1}&signIn=Sign+in", mail, pw);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Comment: The site will likely send an authentication cookie, that you must use for subsequent requests in order to remain authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do: get [live http headers for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and you can record the request your browser sends. Then simply repeat that in code.

for example, the android marketplace does it pretty different from your code.

it actually posts to: `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth`

And posts the data `continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fpublish%2FHome&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fpublish%2FHome&service=androiddeveloper&nui=1&dsh=&GALX=&pstMsg=1&dnConn=&timeStmp=&secTok=&Email=Passwd=&signIn=`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `CookieContainer` instance and assign it to the `CookieContainer` property in each request.

This will store the login cookie so that the site knows that you're still logged in.

Comment: Okay, I added that. Together with Ron's answer below things seem to start working now. But now Google gives me a "cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on." result for my request. Is there anything else I have to consider?

Comment: They probably want a cookie that gets set when you request the login page.

Comment: Could you elaborate that a little further? Because actually I thought that this was what I'm doing?